# Why my timer schedule doesn't execute when calling other method in parallel? - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, task, schedule

I have a library which method calls a previously setted listener (with a lambda expression) and then schedules a task to repeat the metod again.
The problem is that when the program that uses that library receives the response of the listener, if I call another method, the scheduled task never starts.

This is the code from the library:

```
    public void checkLicense(String licenseSerial, String productName) {
                ...

                checkInfo.setReason("VALID");
                this.listener.checkResult(checkInfo);

                time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        checkLicense(licenseSerial, productName);
                    }
                }, 5000); //Check again in 5 seconds
```

And this is the code from the program that sets the listener (with the lambda expression indicating the actions) and calls the Library (Licencheck):

```
  while(typeLicense==null){            
            licencheck.addInvalidLicenseListener(checkInfo -> {
                switch (checkInfo.getReason()){
                    case ("VALID"):{
                        System.out.println("Valid Serial!");
                        serial[1]="ok";
                        Game game = new Game();
                        game.start(); //If I do this call, the Task scheduled doesn't execute
                        break;
                    }

                }
            });

 licencheck.checkLicense(serial[0],"ExampleLicencheck");
```

And the game.start() call that seems that doesn't allow the Task to start:

```
    public void start(){

        while(true){
           ...
        }
    }
```

In resume: 
If the listener responds with "Valid" and there is no game.start() call, the checkLicense executes again (as it is the previous scheduled task). 
If I include in the actions of the response the game.start() call, it starts this method and doesn't executes the task.

Comment: in `case ("VALID")` you have `game.start()` which has `while(true)` and remains in the `while` statement forever and never reaches to the `licencheck.checkLicense(serial[0],"ExampleLicencheck");` line

Comment: If your Game class extends the Thread, then override the run(), not start()

Comment: @user1987 The line `licencheck.checkLicense(serial[0],"ExampleLicencheck");` is called before `game.start()`. This last just executes when receives the listener response of checkLicense, that should have scheduled the new task

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK I tried that, seemed a nice idea. But if inside the run() I introduce the `while(true){...}`, happens the same: the scheduled task in the library method never starts.